# How to attach a link in the setBody of gomail?

Tags: html, go, href

In this code, I am trying to make the `value[2]` as an `href` link so that if somebody clicks on the token, it will be redirected to some page but I am not sure how to do it. I searched for the solution but didn't find it.

```
func SendEmail(value [3]string) {
    mail := gomail.NewMessage()
    myEmail := middleware.LoadEnvVariable("EMAIL")
    myPassword := middleware.LoadEnvVariable("APP_PASSWORD")
    mail.SetHeader("From", myEmail)
    mail.SetHeader("To", value[0])
    mail.SetHeader("Reply-To", myEmail)
    mail.SetHeader("Subject", value[1])
    mail.SetBody("text/html", "<href='localhost:4000'>"+value[2]+"</href>")

    a := gomail.NewDialer("smtp.gmail.com", 587, myEmail, myPassword)
    if err := a.DialAndSend(mail); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyone to answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on [the gomail docs](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/gomail.v2#example-package), try to use the `<a>` tag:

```golang
mail.SetBody("text/html", "<a href=\"" + value[2] + "\">some text</a>")
```

Comment: I did it but the value[2] or token that I receive in an email, does not have a link and is not clickable. It is just a simple text.

Comment: try to use double quote instead of single quote (`<a href=\"localhost:4000\">`)

Comment: use `<a>` tag. not `<href>` tag. 

so it should be `mail.SetBody("text/html", "<a href=\"http://localhost:4000\">"+value[2]+"</a>")`

Comment: FWIW, using raw string literals (those delimited by backticks) allows not to backslash-escape double quotes).

Comment: @hisam Thank you for showing me the correct way!